# what does __global__ mean in the context of a function declaration in c?

Tags: c, cuda, function-declaration

I'm reading a C program where a function is declared like so:

```
__global__ void square(float *d_out, float *d_in);
```

what does the `__global__` specifier mean?

Comment: What's the context? Where did you read this from? Is it CUDA?

Comment: Yes, it's CUDA. I'm following along with a Udacity tutorial for writing a short kernel program.

Comment: Is that supposed to be `_global_` or `__global__` (two different names)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler on some internet pages first `_` has been eaten by the markup engine. I have seen it many times on pages related to CUDA :)

Comment: @marti You should add all that context in your question. I got lucky by googling around and finding a power point presentation from some course that mentions it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not standard C, only some extension or `#define`.

It looks like CUDA.

`__global__` function is executed on GPU, it can be called from CPU or the GPU.

Calling `__global__` functions is often more expensive than `__device__`.

If it is a `#define`, compile the file with the `-E` (gcc) or similar option and see how this macro is expanded.

Comment: Thank you. And @JonathanLeffler, yes it was a double underscore __global__. I found out its purpose is to tell the CUDA compiler that this is kernel code rather than CPU code.

Comment: I would consider removing the "more expensive" line; invoking a kernel and calling a function within a kernel are not exactly comparable.